# iPhone app got rejected due to data storage issue

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

My app was rejected due to data storage problems.
After googling, I got these ideas. Please confirm my assumptions are correct or not.

1. Store the SQLite db in the caches folder and set the "donotbackup" flag, which will stop the file being deleted by the cache clean system.

But what will happen to the db if I update the app to a newer version? Any chance to loss the db?

1. Keep the cache files like images etc. in the Caches folder.

Do we need to clear the cache with our code or the device will clear it automatically?

Then I am storing all the data(including images) in the application's Sqlite db file. So should I implement iCloud in my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use "do not backup" attribute to files that you would to keep, other files place to cache folder. 
Cache folder will be automatically erased when application terminates.

Check this article

[Developers forum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html)

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9)

Comment: So "do not backup" attribute is not related with iCloud, right?

Comment: Files with this attribute will not be uploaded to iCloud.

Comment: But I did not implemented iCloud in my app. Just keeping my sql db and cache images in Documents folder. Any change required?

Comment: iCloud automatically backups all your applications with saves.

Comment: But I think, for that I should configure iCloud in my provisioning profile, is it?

Comment: No. If iCloud turn on it will automatically backups ALL apps.

Comment: Where I can check that whether iCloud is ON for my application? could not find in Settings->iCloud->Storage & Backup.

Comment: You can`t turn it off for custom application. Settings->iCloud->Storage & Backup. -> Manage storage to see all files.

Comment: Now in my app's Documents folder there will be my app's Sql db and some cache images. But in Settings->iCloud->Storage & Backup-> Manage storage, I cannot find anything.

Comment: If sql db have "donotbackup" attribute it should not be in iCloud and apple must approve your application.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. So I should set "donotbackup" property to my db file and place the cache images in the folder Caches. Is it ok? Then one more doubt, I did not configured the iCloud in the appId of my application in developer site.

Comment: From Apple docs: You do not have to prepare your app in any way for backup and restore operations. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9